# Reactjs images and css displaying locally but not when deployed

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

When in I run my app locally npm install, everything looks right. But, when I do npm run build, my css and images are not visible.
My app.css looks like this

```
.Title {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  padding: 1em;
  margin-bottom: 2em;
  background-color: #8A7DDA;
  color: #fff;
}
```

and I am importing my image with
import image from "./images/logo.png";
`<img src={image} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />` 
I have tried
`<img src={require(image)} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />` and also having the image stored in the public folder